# Ignite Cassandra cache configuration - CodecNotFoundException

Tags: caching, cassandra, ignite

I am trying to configure Cassandra as a persistent store for an Apache Ignite 2.0 cache. As a test, I am trying to map key-value pairs to this simple Cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE ignite.cache_test(
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    value int)
```

That's the associated persistence configuration xml I am using:

```
<persistence keyspace="ignite" table="cache_test" ttl="86400">    
    <keyspaceOptions>
        REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}
        AND DURABLE_WRITES = true
    </keyspaceOptions>
    <tableOptions>
        comment = 'Cache test'
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.2
    </tableOptions>
    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key" />
    <valuePersistence class="java.lang.Integer" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="value" />
</persistence>
```

When I try to put elements in the cache using the Ignite REST interface I get:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [int <-> java.lang.String]
```

as if I am trying to map int to String type. I am sure it is a silly configuration error, but I tried several combinations with no success.

For completeness, that's the http call I am sending:

```
http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=put&key=testkey&val=1&cacheName=cache1
```

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

**Change the type of value to text**

So the table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE ignite.cache_test(
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    value text
);
```

And the configuration :

```
<persistence keyspace="ignite" table="cache_test" ttl="86400">    
    <keyspaceOptions>
        REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}
        AND DURABLE_WRITES = true
    </keyspaceOptions>
    <tableOptions>
        comment = 'Cache test'
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.2
    </tableOptions>
    <keyPersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="key" />
    <valuePersistence class="java.lang.String" strategy="PRIMITIVE" column="value" />
</persistence>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have other types mapped as values other than string type with PRIMITIVE strategy?

Comment: @riccamini I haven't work with apache ignite. Your error means you are trying to insert string into int type field and I check their rest api call https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.0/docs/rest-api#put they clearly say that the key is of string type

Comment: Didn't I specify the key field as type String? Or you are suggesting that using the web api all the types will be treated as Strings?

Comment: Yes, strings coming from REST API are not converted to other types. You should follow this response, or insert data using other available APIs (`IgniteCache`, SQL, etc.)